# How can I keep my array values even with an asynchronous call?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that draw lines for each category, and in each of this lines, my function has to put some points, each of them representing a member of the category.

For each member of the family, I put them in an array. To put them in the array, I make 3 query (to get all the informations of the member, retrieved in some table of my database with an API), and put the result of those queries in an array by using zip operator from rxjs and pipe them.

How can I keep my array values even when I'm out of the foreach loop ?

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.serviceData.currentService.subscribe(service =>
        this.serviceFam.getAllFamilles().pipe(
          switchMap(familles => // switchMap to switch into new observable
            forkJoin( // forkJoin to run observables in parrallel
              // map families to observables and run these calls in parallel
              familles.map(f => forkJoin(
                this.serviceAffecter.getAffecterServiceFamille(service, f.nom),
                this.serviceOpe.getOperationsServiceFamille(service, f.nom)
                ).pipe( // gather them all up
                map(([listAffecter, listeOperations]) => [f, listAffecter, listeOperations])
                )
              )
            )
          )
        ).subscribe((data: [Famille, Affecter, Operation][]) => {
          //  now that your observables are done, do the rest.
          this.familles = data.map(d => d[0]);
          for (let d of data) {
            const f = d[0];
            // why are these overwritten at every loop?
            this.listeAffecter = d[1];
            this.listeOperations = d[2];

            //Here is my foreach loop where I put the info of all my members

            for (let a of this.listeAffecter) {
              var accessoire$ = this.serviceAccessoire.getAccessoireByIdAffaire(a.idAffaire);
              var variante$ = this.serviceVar.getVarianteByIdAffaire(a.idAffaire);
              var affaire$ = this.serviceAffaire.getAffaireById(a.idAffaire);

              //Here is where I use zip to put the info in the array

              var combined$ = zip(accessoire$, variante$.pipe(), affaire$.pipe());
              combined$.subscribe(val =>
                this.points.push({
                  "value": this.getTAT(a.dateEntree),
                  "name": val[0].nom + " " + f.nom +
                    " " + val[1].nom + " " + val[2].sn,
                  "operateur": "PERSONNE",
                  "affaire": a.id
                })
              );
            }

            //And this is where I want my data to be keeped

            this.element = document.getElementById(f.nom) as HTMLElement;
            this.element.innerText = "";
            this.draw("#" + f.nom, this.points, {dateDimension: false, color: "teal", labelFormat: "%Y"});
            this.points.length = 0;
            this.operation.length = 0;
          }
        }),
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    this.serviceData.changeAffaire(4);
  }
```

If anybody has an idea on how to do it, it will be cool.

Comment: What do you mean by 'keep'? If you need them outside of the for loop, why don't you assign them to some global class variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you have subscribe inside a subscribe then you are definitely using RxJS wrong. You should instead construct a pipe that modifies the values passed through it, until you have a single result emitted, containing all the data you need. How about you changed your `.subscribe` to something more like this:

```
.pipe(switchMap((data: [Famille, Affecter, Operation][]) => {
  return forkJoin(data.map((f,as,o) => {
    return forkJoin(as.map(a => {
      // Create your combined$ here using zip.
      return combined$;
    }));
  }));
})).subscribe(vals => {
  // Here vals is an array of arrays because of the nested forkJoin.
  this.points = vals.flat().map(val => {
    // Here you transform a value to a point.
  });
  this.draw(...);
});
```

Comment: ok but tu create my combined$, I need a value retrieved by my foreach loop so how can I do it ?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your code properly, hopefully it's better now, please take a look. One ugly thing you do in your original post is assigning `this.listeAffecter` in a loop, which is useless as a field and should just be a local constant. It also confused me somewhat. The same with `listeOperations`, you overwrite it multiple times.